# Using a AJAX, how do I set the innerHTML of an element that is not yet loaded in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

There is a main-feed showing a list of blog post titles. When a title is clicked, I need to display the details of the blog post in a new html file. Below is my current code:

```
 window.location.href = "/viewpost.html";   


    postID = this.id;


    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("view-post-container").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };


    xmlhttp.open("GET", "viewpost.php?q=" + postID, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

The problem is, the element view-post-container, is in the file viewpost.html, and so I don't think the PHP file can access it. I would just display the data on the current page (index.php), but I wanted to have individual pages for each post so I can eventually learn how to have dynamic URL's for SEO and sharing purposes. The end goal is having dynamic urls, so maybe there is a better approach? Any help would is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just try this, You have to put your code in on **window.onload** function

```js
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("view-post-container").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "viewpost.php?q=" + postID, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```